# Filter file name with regex

Tags: groovy, gradle

I was wondering, if there's simpler "Gradle-like" way, how to list files in directory BUT ONLY those, matching regular expression. Currently my solution looks something like this

```
File fileList = file("${moduleDir}/target")
// pattern for maven artifact
def pattern = ~"^.*-[0-9]\\.[0-9]\\.[0-9](-SNAPSHOT)?\\.jar\$"
fileList.listFiles().each { file ->
    if (file.isFile()) {
        if (pattern.matcher(file.getName())) {
            copy {
                from file.getPath()
                into targetDir
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm looking for, is to completely bypassing of manual pattern matching. Are you aware of any method that might help me to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I'm looking for, is to completely bypassing of manual pattern matching

Not quite sure what you mean by that, as you apparently want to match a custom pattern. In any case, I'd use a `Copy` task instead of the `copy` method, and would do the filtering "within" the copy operation. Something like:

```
task copyArtifacts(type: Copy) {       
    from(fileTree(fileList).files) { // flattening
        include {
            it.file.name ==~ "^.*-[0-9]\\.[0-9]\\.[0-9](-SNAPSHOT)?\\.jar\$"
        }
    }
    into targetDir
}
```

PS: Are these your own artifacts? I'm asking because in general, a Maven artifact can use pretty much any version number format.

Comment: Thanks Peter, operand ==~ is what I've been looking for. I feel silly to overlook it in documentation. 
Provided regex is supposed to match all maven artifacts, as far as I know (and obviously I know little :)). I've never came across artifact which would not honor this convention. But thanks for pointing it out, I'll take a deeper look inside maven artifacts (and Nexus repository).

Comment: Some real-world examples that don't match your pattern: `1.0`, `0.12.1`, `1.0.0-beta-1`, `1.0.0.RELEASE`. Of course that's not an exhaustive list. To match such versions, your pattern will need to be less strict.

Comment: Btw, is there a way, how to print files, which are matched by 'it.file.name ==~ ...' construction?

Comment: With a general-purpose language like Groovy under your belt, such things are always possible. You could use plain Groovy code, or a Gradle method like `Copy.eachFile`: `task ... { ... eachFile { println it.file } }`. When faced with such a question, the [DSL reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html) is a good place to start (e.g. check out the docs for the `Copy` task).

Comment: I think it's worth calling out that `==~` is a standard Groovy operator.  http://groovy.codehaus.org/Regular+Expressions