# Is there a way to match directory for regex via gradle like we have for files?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I see there are a couple of ways to get the `File` list and match the files against the regular expression via gradle as listed here: [Filter file name with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584443/filter-file-name-with-regex). Is there a way to do something similar for matching directories as well?, i.e. whether a directory with a regular expression exists in a specific folder via gradle? and if the directory matches the regex, get that directory name to set `System.properties` in `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
file('the/containing/directory').eachDirMatch(~/<your regexp here>/) {
    // set the system property with it.name
}
```